# Fields from form wont show in mailto

Tags: html

I have an html form, from which i take the fields and send them directly to thunderbird ( Or outlook, its the same ) using mailto in the action of the form. The problem is that when a field is in greek ( my language ) it wont show in thunderbird instead it will show some crazy letters but if i the fill the field with english it will show. I tried accept-charset="UTF-8" but nothing and i already have meta charset="UTF-8". Any answer will help me out a lot thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" style="font-size:25px;  font-family:Comic Sans MS" 
name="form1"   action="mailto:karainfo@gmail.com?subject=Question" enctype="text/plain" accept-charset="UTF-8" >

<table >

<tr>


<td>Name *:</td> <td> <input type="text" name="user_name"  size="70" 
id="username" required > </td></tr>

<tr>  <td>  Phone:</td> <td> <input type="number" name="phoneN" size="70" 
id="pho"   > </td></tr>
<tr><td>
    Question*: </td> <td> <textarea name="question" rows="10" cols="70" 
id="que"  required> </textarea></td></tr>

<tr>  <td>  <input type="reset" value="DELETE"> <input type="submit" 
value="SEND" ></td></tr>

<tr><td><strong> Fill the fields with * </strong></td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: Where is your Javascript?

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: Make sure you use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the URI properly.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with html only ?

Answer (score 0):

You have Comic Sans MS font style in your form.
Also, your HTML should have UTF8 charset `<meta charset="utf-8">`.
Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" style="font-size:25px" name="form1"  action="mailto:karainfo@gmail.com?subject=Question" enctype="text/plain"  accept-charset="UTF-8">

<table >

<tr>


<td>Name *:</td> <td> <input type="text" name="user_name"  size="70" 
id="username" required > </td></tr>

<tr>  <td>  Phone:</td> <td> <input type="number" name="phoneN" size="70" 
id="pho"   > </td></tr>
<tr><td>
Question*: </td> <td> <textarea name="question" rows="10" cols="70" 
id="que"  required> </textarea></td></tr>

<tr>  <td>  <input type="reset" value="DELETE"> <input type="submit" 
value="SEND" ></td></tr>

<tr><td><strong> Fill the fields with * </strong></td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not working i have the same problem if i write in greek it will show something like this : ÎŸÏÎµÏƒÏ„Î·Ï‚

Comment: did you remove ```font-family:Comic Sans MS" ``` from the form?

Comment: Yes i removed it